Android build generates this message warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor
When I build my current Android application the build logs include this message.

warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: [room.internal.schemaInput, room.internal.schemaOutput, kapt.kotlin.generated]

However I cannot see where these options are being set and or used.
Do I need to be concerned about them?
My application has multiple modules and the one in question that generates this warning has both room and object box database entities, could that be the issue?
Searching my application files I can find no mention of these options. what is setting them?

Do you use room migration in test?

This warning indicates that some options are being passed to the compiler but are not being used by any annotation processor in your project. If you're unsure about the source of the warning, try cleaning your project and rebuilding it. Check documentation for Room and Kotlin annotation processing to ensure you're using the correct and recommended configurations.
